# Prove that there are positive integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \geq 1$ such that $x_1x_2\ldots x_n = a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for any natural number $n$ and for any natural numbers $a_k, k = 1,\ldots,n,\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\} = \{1,2,\ldots,n\},$ there are positive integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \geq 1$ such that $$x_1x_2\ldots x_n = a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n.$$

Since $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\} = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, we may assume that $a_k = k$ and our equation becomes $$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+nx_n = x_1x_2 \cdots x_n.$$ For example, if $n = 2$ we need $x_1+2x_2 = x_1x_2$. Then we have $x_1(x_2-1) = 2x_2$ and so $x_1 = \dfrac{2x_2}{x_2-1}$, so $x_2 = 2$ and $x_1 = 4$. For $n = 3$ we need $$x_1+2x_2+3x_3 = x_1x_2x_3.$$ Then $x_1(x_2x_3-1) = 2x_2+3x_3$ and $x_1 = \dfrac{2x_2+3x_3}{x_2x_3-1}$ and I didn't see how to choose the $x_i$ here.

Comment: Your investigation of the case $n=1$ is incorrect: There should not be an $x_2$, and you know something very important about $a_1$. -- Anyway, the problem statement itself sounds ... peculiar: By symmetry, we can assume that $a_k=k$, can't we?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, we can assume that $a_k = k$. We have $$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+nx_n = x_1 \cdots x_n.$$

Comment: Just plug $a_k=k$ into the equation and solve it for $x_1$  You get a fraction which needs to be integral, but there is a way to choose the $x_i$ to make it so.  I would do the $n=3$ case as it doesn't have many terms and shows the general behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=3$ you have $x_1 = \dfrac{2x_2+3x_3}{x_2x_3-1}$.  You want to make the division come out even, and an easy way to do so is choose $x_2=2,x_3=1$  so the denominator is $1$.  Now you can just compute that $x_1=7$.  The same approach works for higher $n$.  You have $x_1 = \dfrac{2x_2+3x_3+\ldots +nx_n}{x_2x_3\ldots x_n-1}$.  Choose $x_2=2, x_i=1$ for $3 \le i \le n$ and let $x_1$ come out what it may, which happens to be $1+\frac 12n(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim.** Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer.  For arbitrary integers $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ with $a_0\geq 0$ and $a_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, there exist positive integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ such that $$\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n\,a_ix_i\,.$$

To prove the claim above, we need to only verify the case $n=2$; the case $n>2$ can be reduced to the case $n=2$ by setting $x_3=x_4=\ldots=x_n=1$.  For $n=2$, the equality $x_1x_2=a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2$ is equivalent to
$$\left(x_1-a_1\right)\left(x_2-a_2\right)=a_0+a_1a_2\,.$$
Hence, $x_1=a_1+1$ and $x_2=a_0+a_1a_2+a_2$ form a solution.